# How can i validate DateTimeField using custom validators in models.py in django?

Tags: django, django-models

*models.py*

```py
def validate_date_time(value):
    if value > timezone.now().date():
        raise validationError(" date/time cannot be in past")

Scheduled_date_time=models.DateTimeField(validators=[validate_date_time])
```

I am getting error message:

> Enter a Valid date/time.

But, I am expecting:

> date/time cannot be in past.

Please help...

Comment: What is the datetime you gave?

Comment: datetime is chosen from date time field picker on template with input type 'datetime-local'